# how do I use a button to display <div> in django template?

Tags: javascript, django

`results.html`

```
{%if searched_user %}

<a href= "{{ searched_user }}">{{searched_user}}</a>

    <button id=likedsongsbutton>View liked songs</button>
<div>
{% for each_searched_user in searched_user %}
    <br id="likedsongs"/>{% for liked_songs in each_searched_user.liked_songs.all %}{{liked_songs}} 
<br/>
                            {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
</div>

<script>
    document.querySelector("#likedsongsbutton").addEventListener(onclick, )
</script>
```

`views.py`

```
def results(request):
if request.method == "GET":
    search_query = request.GET.get("username")
    searched_user = UserProfile.objects.filter(
            user__username__contains=search_query
        )
    return render(
    request, "results.html", {
        "searched_user":searched_user
    })
```

My question is how do I make the `<div>` show only when the button is clicked? I do not know what function to pass in the `EventListener`

Comment: are you using bootsrap etc? if not its eassier to create a ```hidden``` css class and add it by default, when you click the button, the event listener, just remove that css clas to make the button visible.

Comment: @Tomek I am just trying to have my `div` block show on the page when I click the `likedsongsbutton`

Comment: For something that is interactive on the page, such as clicking a button to view some data without reloading the page, I'd recommend sticking to javascript to toggle the visibility of the parent div containing the data.
If you want to only load the data onclick, then in this template have an empty content location. Your 'onclick' can then fetch the data from another django endpoint that returns the template you want and set the html of the empty container to that.

Answer (score 0):

If you give your change you div to have an id of myDiv and set the display to be None, you can pass the following lambda in as the second parameter.

```
() => {document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = ""}
```

While the div looks like:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display: none"></div>
```

I also think you should change it from onclick, to "click". Here is a complete example:

```
<button id=likedsongsbutton>View liked songs</button>
<div id="myDiv" style="display: none; background: blue; height: 100px; width: 100px;"></div>
<script>
    document.querySelector("#likedsongsbutton").addEventListener("click", () => {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = ""
    });
</script>
```